# 42P07: Ошибка при обновлении базы Postgre Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, миграция

Я пытаюсь обновить базу используя миграцию EntityFramework но падает вот такая ошибка. Начал смотреть что пишут по этой проблеме, но везде одно и тоже, что не используйте **EnsureCreated** в стартапе и всё. У меня же в стартапе ничего нет такого, вот какой код в стартапе:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUserModel, IdentityRole>(
                options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false
                )
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Ну и понятное дело добавление авторизации, добавление провайдеров и так далее. Но как только пытаюсь запустить обновление базы после миграции падает ошибка которая ниже.

Кто сталкивался с этой проблемой или знает как можно её решить подскажите пожалуйста.

Спасибо большое за ответы!

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
          "Id" text NOT NULL,
          "Name" character varying(256) NULL,
          "NormalizedName" character varying(256) NULL,
          "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
      );
Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
    "Id" text NOT NULL,
    "Name" character varying(256) NULL,
    "NormalizedName" character varying(256) NULL,
    "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: отношение "AspNetRoles" уже существует
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
  Exception data:
    Severity: ОШИБКА
    SqlState: 42P07
    MessageText: отношение "AspNetRoles" уже существует
    File: d:\pginstaller.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\catalog\heap.c
    Line: 1094
    Routine: heap_create_with_catalog
42P07: отношение "AspNetRoles" уже существует
```

Answer (score 0):

Через pgAdmin или SQLShell удалите `AspNetRoles`. Затем, снова попробуйте обновить БД.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]